# Better way to implement Observable sequence

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have been struggling to get the right effect from my sequence of http requests. I have to make an initial request that returns an array of site objects. Then I have to make two more http requests using two id's found in the site object to get the associated sites organization name and team name and add them to each site object. So my steps are:

1. Get list of sites
2. Use site organization id to get related organization and add the name to the site object.
3. Use site team id to get the related team and add the team name to the site object.

My code is as follows:

```
private getSites() {
  this.spinner.show();
  this.sitesService.getSitesByUserId(this.userId)
    .subscribe(
      _data => {
        _data.map(site => {
          this.orgService.getOrganization(site['OrganizationId'])
            .map(org => {
              site['orgName'] = org['org']['name'];
              return org;
            })
            .flatMap(() => this.teamsService.getTeam(site['TeamId']))
            .map(team => {
              site['teamName'] = team['team']['name'];
              return team;
            })
            .subscribe(
              _d => {
                this.sites.push(site);
              }
            );
        });
      },
      _error => {},
      () => {
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.loading = false;
      }
    );
}
```

In my html I am binding the data:

```
<div *ngFor="let site of (sites | filterlist: value : 'name')">
  <card-directory-item (click)="siteSelected(site)">
    <i class="material-icons item-icon">location_city</i>
    <h2 class="item-name">{{ site.name }}</h2>
    <div class="item-field-1">{{ site.city }}  {{ site.state }} </div>
    <div class="item-static-field flex-column">
      <div>{{ site.teamName }}</div>
      <div>{{ site.orgName }}</div>
    </div>
  </card-directory-item>
</div>
```

The problem is the spinner is being removed before all the steps are completed and each list item is popping into place in the order finished. I know why this is happening. I just haven't been able to figure out how to chain the observable stream to finish everything before the spinner is removed and data is displayed.

Any assist would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you `subscribe` to the observable returned by `getSitesByUserId(this.userId)` "too early".

Here your code looks a bit like this

```
this.sitesService.getSitesByUserId(this.userId)
  .subscribe(
    otherAsyncOp,
    errorCallback,
    completeCallback
  )
```

The thing is, the `onCompleteCallback` is being called whenever the observable returned by `getSitesByUserId` has completed which is before your others http requests have completed.

If you want to sequentially call all the url, you will have to use `mergeMap` (or `flatMap` which is an alias) this way

```
this.sitesService.getSitesByUserId(this.userId)
  .mergeMap(sites => Rx.Observable.from(sites)) // create an observable per site
  .mergeMap(site => this.sitesService.getOrga(site.id)
                        .map(orga => Object.assign({}, site, { orgName: orga.org.name }))
  .mergeMap(site => this.sitesService.getTeam(site.teamId).map(team => Object.assign({}, site, {teamName: team.team.name})
  .reduce((sites, site) => sites.concat(site), [])
  .subscribe( /* there every request should be done and you can remove your loader */)
```

Sorry this is a pretty long answer but your question is very broad. I could not execute that code so I am not 100% sure it works, but at least you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. That worked very nicely and I learned a lot from your solution. Actually learned from both. :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your feedback. Learning is the best feeling ever :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You can map each site to a zip of the org and team requests. The third argument of `zip` is a callback that can compose the final object with `Object.assign`.

```
this.sitesService
  .getSitesByUserId(this.userId)
  .mergeMap(sites => Observable.from(sites))
  .mergeMap(site => {
    return Observable.zip(
      this.orgService.getOrganization(site['OrganizationId']),
      this.teamService.getTeam(site['TeamId']),
      (org, team) => Object.assign(site, {
        orgName: org['org']['name'],
        teamName: team['team']['name']
      })
    )
  })
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: This is nice code but it does not work in my case. I believe this would work if site within mergeMap was a single site object, but in my case it's an array of site objects. So when your code makes the call for this.teamService.getTeam(site['TeamId']), the id is undefined.

Comment: I see. So you just need another `mergeMap`. Code fixed.